# Use pem file for remote access to Windows EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to remotely accessa Windows Server EC2 instance via my PEM file? e.g remote command over powershell? or are PEM files only useful for Linux/SSH instance? If so, why does AWS generate a PEM file for Windows Instances?

If someone has my PEM file can they access my Windows EC2 remotely via powershell or other?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on [Amazon EC2 key pairs and Windows instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html).

To access a Windows instance via RDP you need the Administrator password. To get the initial Administrator password you need:

- the private key (PEM file), and
- IAM permissions to call the EC2 [GetPasswordData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_GetPasswordData.html) API

Access to the PEM file alone does not allow you to retrieve the initial Administrator password and hence you cannot RDP to the Windows instance with only the PEM file.

The PEM file can only be used to retrieve the initial Administrator password. You can do that as often as you like, but only for the initial Administrator password. Once you change the Windows Administrator password, the PEM file cannot be used to retrieve the password.

Comment: So as far as I can tell the PEM file is for recovery only if you lose the admin password? Can you only use the PEM file to recover from within the AWS Console?

Comment: Also if I change my windows admin password my pem file will be worthless even if someone decrypts it, is this correct? since the password would have changed?

Comment: You need to use the PEM file to retrieve the Administrator password before your first RDP attempt, but it's also potentially useful for subsequent recovery. You can use the PEM file with any supported AWS SDK client such as the awscli [get-password-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html), a client written to use boto3, etc.

Comment: but if the RDP password is now changed via changing the passsword in Windows,the PEM file will no longer work right?

Comment: You could verify this in practice, but it is my understanding that the PEM file can only be used to retrieve the initial Administrator password. You can do that as often as you like, but only for the initial Administrator password. Once you change the Windows Administrator password, the PEM file cannot be used to retrieve the password.

Comment: The password retrieved via the console or the [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_GetPasswordData.html) is the password that [EC2Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2config-service.html) creates and outputs in the system log.  As [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html), "The console can only retrieve the default password"